# Passing an array to a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to recreate the game 2048 in C++.

I'm working on a `spawn` function right now. It takes in an array of the current values of the 16 spots, randomly scans for an empty one, and puts either a 2 or a 4 in that spot.

I am starting out with a test array, `b`. I want to pass this array to a function that will alter one of its values, which I know I need to do by passing a pointer, but none of the changes are staying after I leave the function.

Can anyone see what is wrong here? How do I properly pass the array in so the changes will stay after the spawn function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void showBoard(int board[]);
void spawn(int* board);

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int b[16] = {2, 2, 2, 2};
    int* bp = b;

    showBoard(b);
    spawn(bp);
    showBoard(b);
}

// print out the 16 current tiles to the console
void showBoard(int board[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<=15; ++i){
        if(i%4==0)
            cout<<'\n';
        cout<<board[i]<<"     ";
    }
    cout<<'\n';
}

void spawn(int* board) {
    int x; // index

    // randomly choose an index to spawn a 2 or 4:
    do x=rand()%16; while(board[x]!=0);
    // when found empty place (with value 0), spawn a new tile.
    /* there should be a 90% chance of spawning a 2
     * and a 10% chance of spawning a 4. Generate a
     * random number between 0 and 9, and if it is
     * 9, make the new spawn tile a 4.
     */
    if (rand()%10 == 9) {
        board[x] == 4;
        cout << "added 4 \n";
    }
    else {
        board[x] == 2;
        cout << "added 2 \n";
    }
}
```

The output:

```
2     2     2     2
0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0
added 2 
2     2     2     2
0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0
```

So my `cout` confirms that I got to the if block where I would set `board[x]` to 2, but when I do `showBoard` afterwards, there is no update to the array. Any help?

Comment: You are passing array by pointer.

Comment: This does not change anything in the array: `board[x] == 2;`.

Comment: This is a good example of a `cout` being helpful but also allowing you to jump to conclusions. You should have examined that `else` block with a fine-toothed comb.

Comment: When there is no free place, your code enters infinite loop, trying find free place.

Answer (score 4):

```
board[x] == 2;
board[x] == 4;
```

Need to be:

```
board[x] = 2;
board[x] = 4;
```

Also, it may make the code simpler if you make this a 2D 4x4 array. Picking a random square would then become:

```
int x = rand() % 16;
int board_spot = board[x%4][x/4];
```